# Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, python-3.5, segmentation-fault, linux-mint

I'm trying to execute a [Python script](https://pastebin.com/jSjn1aaD), but I am getting the following error:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I'm using python 3.5.2 on a Linux Mint 18.1 Serena OS

Can someone tell me why this happens, and how can I solve?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The SIGSEGV signal indicates a "[segmentation violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)" or a "segfault".  More or less, this equates to a read or write of a memory address that's not mapped in the process.

This indicates a bug in your program.  In a Python program, this is either a bug in the interpreter or in an extension module being used (and the latter is the most common cause).

To fix the problem, you have several options.  One option is to produce a minimal, self-contained, complete example which replicates the problem and then submit it as a bug report to the maintainers of the extension module it uses.

Another option is to try to track down the cause yourself.  [gdb](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gdb) is a valuable tool in such an endeavor, as is a debug build of Python and all of the extension modules in use.

After you have gdb installed, you can use it to run your Python program:

```
gdb --args python <more args if you want>
```

And then use gdb commands to track down the problem.  If you use `run` then your program will run until it would have crashed and you will have a chance to inspect the state using other gdb commands.

Answer (score 22):

Another possible cause (which I encountered today) is that you're trying to read/write a file which is open. In this case, simply closing the file and rerunning the script solved the issue.

Answer (score 10):

After some times I discovered that I was running a new TensorFlow version that gives error on older computers. I solved the problem downgrading the TensorFlow version to 1.4

Comment: my case was resolved after using tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0 rather that 1.8.0.

Answer (score 6):

When I encounter this problem, I realize there are some memory issues. I rebooted PC and solved it.

Answer (score 6):

This can also be the case if your C-program (e.g. using `cpython` is trying to access a variable out-of-bound

```
ctypedef struct ReturnRows:
    double[10] your_value

cdef ReturnRows s_ReturnRows # Allocate memory for the struct
s_ReturnRows.your_value = [0] * 12
```

will fail with

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Answer (score 4):

For me, I was using the OpenCV library to apply SIFT.
In my code, I replaced cv2.SIFT() to cv2.SIFT_create() and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 3):

**PYCHARM USERS**

For a subset of people who find this problem, this might help. Turns out it can also be a PyCharm Debugger issue. Searching the internet for the issue and pycharm as a keyword turns up many results (maybe would too for other IDE debuggers).

Users suggested turning off PyQT compatibility in the debugger, amongst other things.

For me, weirdly this answer worked:

[python/pycharm project produces segmentation fault in debug mode, but not in run mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70483839/python-pycharm-project-produces-segmentation-fault-in-debug-mode-but-not-in-run)
(turning ON collecting runtime types in settings->build->python debugger)

Comment: This worked for me too in PyCharm 2023.2.5

Answer (score 2):

Deleted the python interpreter and the 'venv' folder solve my error.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error in PHP, while running PHPUnit. The reason was a circular dependency.

Comment: What kind of circular dependency?

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error when trying to connect to an Oracle DB using the `pyodbc` module:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect()
```

The error occurred on the following occasions:

- The DB connection has been opened multiple times in the same python
  file
- While in debug mode a breakpoint has been reached
  while the connection to the DB being open

The error message could be avoided with the following approaches:

- Open the DB only once and reuse the connection at all needed places
- Properly close the DB connection after using it

Hope, that will help anyone!

Answer (score 1):

**11 : SIGSEGV** - This signal is arises when a memory segement is illegally accessed.

There is a module name **signal** in python through which you can handle this kind of OS signals.

If you want to ignore this **SIGSEGV** signal, you can do this:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, signal.SIG_IGN)
```

However, ignoring the signal can cause some inappropriate behaviours to your code, so it is better to handle the **SIGSEGV** signal with your defined handler like this:

```
def SIGSEGV_signal_arises(signalNum, stack):
    print(f"{signalNum} : SIGSEGV arises")
    # Your code

signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, SIGSEGV_signal_arises)
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to run my script putting this somewhere between my code: 
`import signal`
`def SIGSEGV_signal_arises(signalNum, stack):`
  `pass`
`signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, SIGSEGV_signal_arises)`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I was trying to run my code on an external GPU which was disconnected. I set `os.environ['PYOPENCL_CTX']=2` where GPU 2 was not connected. So I just needed to change the code to os.environ`['PYOPENCL_CTX'] = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

For me these three lines of code already reproduced the error, **no matter how much free memory was available**:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0], [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=1, random_state=0).fit(X)
```

I could solve the issue by removing an reinstalling the `scikit-learn` package. A very similar solution to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841196/11671205).

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur if trying to compound threads using concurrent.futures. For example, calling .map inside another .map call.

This can be solved by removing one of the .map calls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue working with kmeans from scikit-learn.
Upgrading from scikit-learn 1.0 to 1.0.2 solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is often caused by incompatible libraries in your environment. In my case, it was the `pyspark` library.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, reverting my most recent conda installs fixed the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when importing monai. It was solved after I created a new conda environment. Possible reasons I could imagine were either that there were some conflict between different packages, or maybe that my environment name was the same as the package name I wanted to import (monai).

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was a pickled file, specifically a pandas DataFrame.
deleting the pickled file fixed the issue.

similar to this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame()

# somewhere
df.from_pickle('my_path.p')

# somewhere later
df.to_pickle('my_path.p')
```

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) error

the problem is with import cv2. you need to use pip install numpy==1.24.3

this version of numpy fixed it. the newest version of numpy must be broken

Answer (score 0):

After reeboting the syste, its working fine, but its keep on coming wheb tensorflow is using

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

found on other page.
interpreter: python 3.8

cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

this solved issue for me. 
i was getting SIGSEGV with 2.7, upgraded my python to 3.8 then got different error with OpenCV. and found answer on [OpenCV 4.0.0 SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54273050/opencv-4-0-0-systemerror-class-cv2-cascadeclassifier-returned-a-result-with).

but eventually one line of code fixed it.