# WARNING: QApplication was not created in main() thread

Tags: python, linux, pycharm, segmentation-fault

When I try to develop a parallel python application using the ~threading module~, I get the following error

> Python Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
>   SIGSEGV)"

I'm using python 3.6 ,Linux 16.04 and Pycharm 2018

I cannot understand the reason and how to fix it.

Code Sample:

```
numOfThread = 8
class myThread (threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self, thread_id, name, frames):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.thread_id = thread_id
      self.name = name
      self.frames = frames
      self.out_frame = None

   def run(self):
      print("Starting " + self.name)
      self.out_frame = trackingmario(self.frames)


list_of_threads = []

print("Start.....\n")

for i in range(numOfThread):
    list_of_threads.append(myThread(i, 'thread_'+str(i), lists[i]))


for i in range(numOfThread):
    list_of_threads[i].start()

for ti in list_of_threads:
    ti.join()
```

[Image show the error : "Python Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RhW7.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414841/python-process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-signal-11-sigsegv)

Comment: Can you try to replace this line `self.out_frame = trackingmario(self.frames)` with `print("{} {}".format(self.name, len(self.frames)))`. If this works, then the issue is in the trackingmario method