# How to avoid PyCharm console crash "WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread" when plotting with matplotlib?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, matplotlib, pycharm

In PyCharm, when I try to plot something using its interactive console, such as:

```
In[2]: from matplotlib.pyplot import *
In[3]: x = range(5)
In[4]: y = range(5,10)
In[5]: plot(x,y)
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fade916a438>]
In[6]: show()
```

It opens a window and crashes. I have to stop the console and start a new one.

[image: screenshot of the error]

It works fine when I run anything like that in an ipython console in my terminal, the error happens only in Pycharm, it seems.

On the other hand, if import matplotlib with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` it works fine:

```
In[2]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In[3]: x = range(5)
In[4]: y = range(5,10)
In[5]: plt.plot(x,y)
Out[5]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fd3453b72e8>]
In[6]: plt.show()
```

But if I do both, it crashes too (even calling the plot function using `plt.plot`):

```
In[2]: from matplotlib.pyplot import *
In[3]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In[4]: x = range(5)
In[5]: y = range(5,10)
In[6]: plt.plot(x,y)
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
Out[6]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fade916a438>]
In[7]: plt.show()
```

Furthermore, when I run it all in one command, it works the first time. But if I try to plot another time, it crashes:

```
In[2]: from matplotlib.pyplot import *
  ...: x = range(5)
  ...: y = range(5,10)
  ...: plot(x,y)
  ...: show()
In[3]: plot(x,y)
WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fc68a3009e8>]
In[4]: show()
```

So it is something related with using the matplotlib library with the import using * and with running in the interactive console after the first time it was imported. I know the wildcard import is not recommended, but sometimes it is useful to do it for a sake of testing things faster and being less verbose.

Looking for this warning online, I have only found these

- https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13296
  But my case doesn't seem to be related to multiprocessing. And even if pycharm is doing something behind the scenes, I wonder why it has changed, as I had no problems with this like a month ago;
- [Suppress warning "QApplication was not created in main() thread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963697/suppress-warning-qapplication-was-not-created-in-main-thread)
  and other posts related to C++, which is not my case;
- [WARNING: QApplication was not created in main() thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076262/warning-qapplication-was-not-created-in-main-thread) -> related to pycharm, but has an additional error different than mine

Which didn't help much. Anyone knows what is happening and how to solve it?

SPECS:

- PyCharm 2019.1.2 (Professional Edition)
- Build #PY-191.7141.48, built on May 7, 2019
- JRE: 11.0.2+9-b159.56 amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- Linux 4.15.0-50-generic
- conda 4.6.14, with Python 3.7.3
- Qt5

Comment: `import *` [is discouraged](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) anyway. Besides that, you have a likely relevant warning to investigate, which you don't appear to have done.

Comment: I have investigated, but it is very generic, so I couldn't find anything that seemed to explain how to fix it in this case. That's the only reason why I posted it in the first place. Also, the wildcard is discourage in the final code, I'm using it in the console just for debugging. I don't think the -1 is fair in this case.

Comment: If you investigated it, you need to include what you learned about it in the question.

Comment: Ok, I have done that now. Better?

Comment: This seems to be pycharm specific, so it might help to state the pycharm version (and other possible settings) you're using.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest added more specs. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sent this question to JetBrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36136

They couldn't find a solution yet, but the workaround they suggested is the following:

Disable **Show plots in tool window** in **File | Settings | Tools | Python Scientific**.

This worked for me, although it doesn't plot in the PyCharm window.

Comment: If no one finds a better solution, I will accept my own answer as the solution so far. I don't know if that is allowed in a bounty...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350068/can-i-answer-my-own-bounty
It is possible but I don't get the reputation back. Well... I hope it is useful for others at least. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There several things you can try:

First, you can try to update the Qt. You may have some older version. Run

```
print(plt.get_backend())
```

to verify which backend you are using. If you are using `Qt4`, try `Qt5` back end.

Next, update `Qt5` to the latest version via

```
pip install --upgrade PyQt5
```

Also, you can try ditching `Qt` and switch to `Tk` back end: add

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

before importing `pyplot`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work, though. I am already using Qt5. I run `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` and the output is `Qt5Agg`. The switch to `Tk` back didn't change the error either. :-(

Comment: `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` should be your very first lines. Once you import `pyplot` this will not work anymore, and you can not switch backends once `pyplot` was initialized

Comment: That's exactly what I did, I run `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('TkAgg'); from matplotlib.pyplot import *` and then the rest. Each command in one line (I can't do this in a comment). I am sorry, I just realised that my previous answer was confusing. I meant: I am already using Qt5. I run `print(plt.get_backend())` and the output was `Qt5Agg`. The switch to `Tk` back end didn't change the error either.

Comment: Try uninstalling `PyQt5` and `matplotlib`, and reinstalling them again

Comment: I don't think it would work, as the problem is the same in more than one conda environment

Comment: And it was replicated by this guy from jetbrains: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36136