# OpenCV 4.0.0 SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, opencv, facial-identification

Hello I am trying to create a facial recognition program but I have a peculiar error:
here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
face_cascade = cv.CascadeClassifier("lbpcascade_frontalface.xml")
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5);
```

and this error is the output

```
SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set
```

I have "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml" in the working directory so that shouldn't be an issue

if it helps when I enter

```
cv.__version__
```

I get

```
'4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**New Answer**
OpenCV seems to now have a directory dedicated to cascades, they are placed in `data` and I am seeing something like this floating around in tutorials now
`haar_cascade_face = cv.CascadeClassifier('data/haarcascade/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`
You may have to find where `data` is on your machine or the above my work. I have not touched this project since I finished it in early 2019.
Bear in mind this only works for frontal face, if you want to use Haar's Cascade for eyes that is a separate file.

**old answer**
Turns out I didn't need to download another file and use it because opencv comes with it this little bit of code worked

```
cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'data'

Comment: I down-voted this answer, I'm getting the same answer listed in the comment above.

Comment: I edited the answer after some research, sorry you two had errors that I didn't get to sooner but I have not touched OpenCV since last year almost.

Comment: In my case, there is no folder named 'data' comes with opencv library; instead, search for the folder 'haarcascades' which is within a folder named 'etc' in Win10 OS.

Comment: works,  `windows10` , cv2 version  `4.5.1`, using `pip install opencv-python`.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Well I was in this same problem, as @TylerStrouth mentioned this code snippet doesn't work :

```
cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

because there are no haarcascades files in data directory if you have just installed *opencv* in a standard format of `pip install opencv-python` or `sudo apt-get install python3-opencv`

You will get an error something similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633378/attributeerror-module-cv2-cv2-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer), therein is the mentioned solution that worked for me, that is if you're using python3 then you need also to install *opencv-contrib-python* before running the above code snippet.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

which has full package (contains both [main modules and contrib/extra modules](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/))

Answer (score 1):

On version `3.4.9.33` of opencv-python (`pip show opencv-python`, Windows) the below line works fine: `trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')`

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @TylerStrouth above opencv has a directory of cascades in which the cascade files are available, I also faced the same problem while running the code for face detection on Ubuntu 16.04 and solved it as follows

1. Get the location of opencv using

   whereis opencv
2. Mine was in /usr/share/opencv
3. Check whether the cascades are present in that location and copy paste the location in cv2.CascadeClassifier along with the required haarcascade

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered same issue in little different way.
I was using Jupiter notebook to execute code [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-perform-face-detection-with-classical-and-deep-learning-methods-in-python-with-keras/)

I copied XML file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml) and created a XML file in current Jupiter directory, when loading this files using below:

```
classifier = CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
```

Its returned me error :

```
SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an error set
```

So, I tried other way, removed this file, and downloaded actual file as XML format in current directory, which resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

**I was having the same error** when i was using `hogcascade_pedestrians.xml` to detect pedestrians from a local video and i was reading the `hogcascade_pedestrians.xml` as follows:

```
pedestrainsClassifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier("hogcascade_pedestrians.xml")
```

**Of which you should read it as follows:**

```
pedestrainsClassifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(f"{cv2.data.haarcascades}hogcascade_pedestrians.xml")
```

**Alternatively you can do it as follows:**

```
pedestrainsClassifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades +"hogcascade_pedestrians.xml")
```

**Good luck**

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows, this worked for me

`har_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades +'har.xml')`

Comment: did you proof-read or execute that code before you posted it as an answer? what do you think `"har.xml"` is?