# How to fix" process finished with exit code 139(interrupted by signal 11:sigsegv)" when use import rpy2.robjects

Tags: python, r

I am using python to call r by code 'import rpy2.robjects',but failed.

The error is: Process finished with exit code 139(interrupted by signal 11:SIGSEGV）

I have tried  two rpy2 version,including  2.9.4 or 2.9.1,and only import ryp2 without error.

Comment: python version 3.7  R version 3.7

Comment: What is your OS? Did you properly and successfully install `rpy2`?

Comment: [Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414841/process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-signal-11-sigsegv) ... might not even involve `rpy2`.