# OpenCV- Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) on MAC

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, pycharm

Getting Error Like

> Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11:
> SIGSEGV)

when i run below code in pycharm.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("MyFriends.jpg")
cv2.imshow("TEST",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Solution Tried :** `sudo chmod -R 777 to targetfolder`
but no change.

Closing and reopening the IDE didn’t help.

Rebooting the laptop didn’t help

**Python Version:**  3.8.5

**opencv version:** 4.4.0

[image]

Comment: Let's see some code

Comment: This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49414841/process-finished-with-exit-code-139-interrupted-by-signal-11-sigsegv) may be useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked the previous OpenCV versions. The issue persists on 4.3.0.38, but not on '4.3.0.36'. So whatever is causing it, started on that version.

I guess I continue using '4.3.0.36' for now...

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Raj Singh, opencv version 4.3.0.36 is perfectly working in mac

Answer (score 0):

Usually because you are referencing an object that no longer exists.

Are you realeasing the videocapture too early (if you are using it)

Or

Are you calling `cv2.destroyallwindows()` whithin your while loop?

Both of these, if inside your while loop, would cause the error.

If the above code is all you have so far...

Try

`import cv2

img = cv2.imread("MyFriends.jpg")

cv2.imshow("TEST",img)

cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()`

Comment: I am not using any loop, i am trying to execute above code and getting strange error.

Comment: Did you try the code at the bottom? Have you tried stepping through the code. Which line does it fail on?

Comment: On what line does it crash.

Comment: Try `cv2.namedWindow("TEST")` before you call imshow. This creates the window first. It's worth a shot

Comment: above same code working in jupiter notebook but cause error in pycharm

Comment: Are you using a different environment in pycharm? Try opening the console in pycharm and reinstalling opencv