# Segmentation fault: 11 python after upgrading to OS Big Sur

Tags: python, matplotlib, macos-big-sur

Yesterday, my program was working perfectly fine. However, today it stopped working. I think that it may have something to do with the latest Mac OS update, as I had just installed it today. My testing code is shown below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
print("ehllow")
zeroes = np.zeros((10,10))
plt.imshow(zeroes)
plt.show()
```

Everything is going fine until I get to plt.show(). I had tried removing it, and the program ran smoothly, but once I added it back in I got the error

> Segmentation fault: 11

and then it shows a python crash screen[image]

I have python version 3.7.6 64 bit for Mac.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok. Just for anyone wondering

Just uninstalling and reinstalling the packages that were giving the error worked for me

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue - a Python program that was working fine before updating to Big Sur, and crashing with:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

after updating.

As previous responses have advised, just uninstalling and reinstalling the offending Python libraries fixed the problem.  For me, that meant matplotlib:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib 
pip install matplotlib
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uninstalling it and reinstalling the latest python update and restarting you PC/Laptop?

Comment: The problem is, is many of my other modules that I need(not shown) are not supported beyond 3.7.6, so it would be ideal if I didn't have to upgrade my latest python. The program was working on the same python version before the latest Mac update as well.

Comment: Do you think that you there is a compatibility setting on MacOS like how you can run exe files and programs in "compatabilaty mode" in windows 10?

Comment: I have no idea honestly. Probably not. I still do not know what's causing the issue

Comment: Also, a lot of the modules aren't compatible for 3.9, so upgrading is not ideal

Comment: I really don't know. I don't know much about mac-OS, but I know how it feels when something just doesn't work. I hope someone comes around and figures this out.

Comment: No Problem @green142f

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue:
**Segmentation fault: 11**

I guess, it is because of the statement line:
**plt.show()**

As stated above, uninstallation and reinstallation of matplotlib worked for me.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling is the best option but you can also use:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('MacOSX')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

i had to drop my dpi from 400 to 50 on the OSX machine.  none of these other approaches worked.  fwiw, my update was to Catalina, not Big Sur.