# Jupyter session crashing when attempting to train network

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to create the LeNet neural network using PyTorch for a lab exercise and train it on the MNIST dataset using the GPU. I'm using a Jupyter notebook on my local machine.

Training the network works fine if I use a Google Colab hosted runtime (CPU and GPU), and also works if I use my local CPU but it crashes if I try to use the local GPU. I also have code for a basic linear network which works fine on my GPU. As far as I'm aware I've set everything up correctly and am following the instructions that were given to me.

This is the code I have written for the LeNet CNN

```python
# Importing all dependencies
import os # for some OS ops
import torch
from torch import nn
torch.manual_seed(0)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False

from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms
import torchvision

from torchvision.datasets import MNIST  # The data set that we will use

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import time

class LeNet(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, inputSize=28 * 28, outputSize=10, lr=0.01):
    super().__init__()
    self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=6, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(6),
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    )
    self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(6, 16, kernel_size=5, padding=0),
        nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        nn.Sigmoid(),
        nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    )
    self.fc = nn.Linear(400, 120)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.relu1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(84, outputSize)

    # Setting the learning rate
    self.lr = lr

  ## The forward step
  def forward(self, x):
    # the crash occurs during the next line of code, with no output
    out = self.layer1(x)
    out = self.layer2(out)
    out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
    out = self.fc(out)
    out = self.relu(out)
    out = self.fc1(out)
    out = self.relu1(out)
    out = self.fc2(out)
    return out
    

  ## The loss function - Here, we will use Cross Entropy Loss
  def loss(self, y_hat, y):
    fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() # see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html
    return fn(y_hat, y)

  ## The optimization algorithm
  def configure_optimizers(self):
    return torch.optim.Adam(self.parameters(), self.lr)

class Trainer:

  def __init__(self, n_epochs = 3):
    self.max_epochs = n_epochs
    return

  # The fitting step
  def fit(self, model, data):

    self.data = data

    # configure the optimizer
    self.optimizer = model.configure_optimizers()
    self.model     = model

    for epoch in range(self.max_epochs):
      epoch_start_time = time.time()
      self.fit_epoch()
      print("Epoch " + str(epoch) + " finished in " + str(time.time() - epoch_start_time) + "s")

    print("Training process has finished")

  def fit_epoch(self):

    current_loss = 0.0

    # iterate over the DataLoader for training data
    # This iteration is over the batches
    # For each batch, it updates the network weights and computes the loss
    for i, data in enumerate(self.data):
      # Get input and its corresponding groundtruth output
      inputs, target = data

      # Clear gradient buffers because we don't want any gradient from previous
      # epoch to carry forward, dont want to cummulate gradients
      self.optimizer.zero_grad()

      # get output from the model, given the inputs
      # crashes while doing this
      outputs = self.model(inputs)

      # get loss for the predicted output
      loss = self.model.loss(outputs, target)

      # get gradients w.r.t the parameters of the model
      loss.backward()

      # update the parameters (perform optimization)
      self.optimizer.step()

      # Let's print some statisics
      current_loss += loss.item()
      if i % 500 == 499:
          print('Loss after mini-batch %5d: %.3f' %
                (i + 1, current_loss / 500))
          current_loss = 0.0

# Training on the GPU

def to_device(data, device):
    # Move tensor(s) to chosen device
    if isinstance(data, (list,tuple)):
        return [to_device(x, device) for x in data]
    return data.to(device, non_blocking=True)

class DeviceDataLoader():
    # Wrap a dataloader to move data to a device
    def __init__(self, dl, device):
        self.dl = dl
        self.device = device

    def __iter__(self):
        # Yield a batch of data after moving it to device
        for b in self.dl:
            yield to_device(b, self.device)

    def __len__(self):
        # Number of batches
        return len(self.dl)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
#device = torch.device("cpu") # to force it to use CPU
print(device)

# 1. Loading the MNIST data set
# Transforms to apply to the data
transform = transforms.Compose([
  transforms.Resize((28,28)), # I dont think I need this but it doesnt work either  way
  transforms.ToTensor()])

# Loading the data
train_dataset = MNIST(os.getcwd(), train=True, download=True, transform=transform)

batch_size = 10
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)
trainloader = DeviceDataLoader(trainloader, device)

# 2. The CNN model
cnn_model = LeNet(lr=1e-04)
to_device(cnn_model, device)

# 3. Training the network
# 3.1. Creating the trainer class
trainer = Trainer(n_epochs=1)

# 3.2. Training the model
trainer.fit(cnn_model, trainloader)
```

I cannot find any error logs. Jupyter simply says that the kernel appears to have died, with no additional information. I don't believe it's a memory issue, I have 16GB of available system ram (32GB total) and the gpu is an RTX 4090 so plenty of vram.

Comment: Maybe reading through this question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74154123/how-to-debug-jupyter-kernel-crashes

Comment: @Lfppfs that gave me the info needed to fix it, thanks